# Writing Index and LinEst formulas in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy the next scenario to `VBA`?

[image]

My problem is writing the formula using `VBA` script.

I already did the following:

```
Sub CALC()
        Dim X(1 to 10) as Double
        Dim Y(1 to 10) as Double
        Dim QUA_A as Double
    '--------
        For N = 1 to 10
            X(N) = Cells(N, 1).Value
            Y(N) = Cells(N, 2).Value         
        Next N
    '--------
        QUA_A = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(X, Y ^ [1,2]), 1)
End Sub
```

However, I got a syntax error on the line `QUA_A = ...`

What am I missing? Thanks.

**NOTE:**

I guess I misled you guys on my quest.
First of all, it's NOT my intention to work with ranges. The true problem involves much larger arrays and would take too long to run the entire procedure if I write the arrays (even on a `xlVeryHidden` sheet). I just use this sheet (of the image) to explain this question.
Second of all, when I use the command

```
QUA_A = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(X, Y), 1)
```

there's no error raising and the value is the same as it's equivalent

```
=INDEX(LINEST(A1:A10;B1:B10);1)
```

so, it looks obvious to me that both formulas deal well with arrays instead of ranges.

Comment: What does it show if you turn on the macro recorder, then enter that formula in the spreadsheet? It should return a formula you could use.  Also, why not set `y` and `x` as ranges, and use that in the formula? `Set Y = Range("A1:A10") / Set X = Range("B1:B10)`.  Then, `...LinEst(Y, X^{1,2}...`?

Comment: Check in Locals what values are assigned into X and Y. May be something wrong there.

Comment: @BruceWayne, that's not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to write the value on the cell. I want to record the value to the `QUA_A` variable. I just made the sheet you see on the picture for this question.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos, there's nothing wrong with the arrays. It's a syntax error. It's just the way the formula is written.

Comment: Using Bruce's approach you don't have to write the value to a cell. My guess is the problem is `[1,2]` but I don't know. Have you tried using `Evaluate` function?

Comment: @SJR, but I have to have the values on the sheet (and I don't want to). However, I just tried to do this with ranges instead of arrays and got the same error.

Comment: So in reality how are your arrays populated?

Comment: @SJR, I also think the problem is `[1,2]`. Already tried `{1,2}` and the error persists. The arrays are populated with another macros.

Comment: Not sure what the formula does, but another problem may be trying to use index on an array.

Comment: @SGR, already tested. If I take out `^ [1,2]`, the formula works fine.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542670/vba-use-linest-to-calculate-polynomial-coefficients-and-index-to-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the X a two dimensional array, and do the math part before the formula:

```
Sub CALC()
        Dim X(1 To 2, 1 To 10) As Double
        Dim Y(1 To 10) As Double
        Dim QUA_A As Double
    '--------
        For n = 1 To 10
            X(1, n) = Cells(n, 2).Value
            X(2, n) = Cells(n, 2).Value ^ 2
            Y(n) = Cells(n, 1).Value
        Next n
    '--------
        QUA_A = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X), 1)
        Debug.Print QUA_A
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get the same values on both ways. But, at least, I don't get an error anymore.

Comment: I get the same result if you put the same range in the same variable.  In the formula you are putting column A in as the Y and in vba you are putting column B as Y.  @Pspl

Comment: Yes! Thanks for notice. I already changed my original post as yours... Let me check again...

Comment: @Pspl changed the columns.

Comment: How much are you getting??

Comment: `0.677035912999494` from both vba above, I changed your edit, and the formula: `=INDEX(LINEST(A1:A10,B1:B10^{1,2}),1)` @Pspl

Comment: @Pspl you may need to refresh the screen to see my edit.

Comment: Got it!!!! Just had to write {1\2} on my formula because my regional definitions. So your `VBA` way is truthfully correct! Tanks a lot @Scott Craner.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not getting the same result as you are, you could try the below.

<sub>(Note you may need to switch the `,`for `;` since it looks like your location settings are different than mine)</sub>

```
Sub calc2()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim QUA_A as Variant
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A10")
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

QUA_A = Evaluate("=INDEX(LINEST(" & rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address & "^{1,2}),1)")

Range("D2").Value = QUA_A

End Sub
```

(I get `0.677035912999494`)

Comment: Seriously, again, if I wanted to use ranges, I just use the formula I wrote. I'm sorry but I'm looking for a solution without writing the arrays on the sheet, so... Both formulas `Index` and `LinEst` work fine with arrays. They don't require ranges to work!